# Finite Element software for chemical diffusion in liquid

Tags: finite-element-method

I'm an engineer who needs to do FEA for the first time.  I need to model chemical diffusion in a liquid in a container with specific geometry.  For now fluid is assumed to be not flowing.

What features do I need to look for in FE software to get this done?  Diffusion doesn't fall under fluid dynamics does it?  It's not thermal (though I think it may be mathematically similar) or structural either.

Specific software suggestions are also welcome.  I suspect my needs are basic so ease of use would be nice too.

Comment: Unless you have a density gradient from bottom to top in the fluid, it *will* flow as the diffusion takes place.

Comment: If you can work with a general purpose solver for problems that do not involve too much complexity (e.g., 10,000 parts etc.), I'd suggest Comsol.  However, you may need to know the equations you will solve and how to create a FE weak form if there isn't a module that was explicitly designed for that sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Phoenics, sold by Cham.

Seen models of smoke through air in a city and blood through heart valves so it is very powerful, but not cheap...

There are others StarCD etc

Answer (score 0):

Check [openFOAM](https://openfoam.org/) and in particular its solver interMixingFoam

You can visit https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/guides/latest/api/interMixingFoam_8C.html

And maybe contact the asker of this question in SE: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21040/how-to-model-the-mixing-of-two-fluids-in-a-container